# I want to apply the default values to the program in python tkinter

Tags: python, function, user-interface, tkinter, project

I am making a restaurant management system, So, in the settings menu, I included an option to change the prices of the food items, instead of always writing the food item prices, i want there to be some default prices of the food, but it is not working as expected, please check the code below first:

```
def settings():
sett = Toplevel(Tops)
sett.title('Settings')
sett.geometry('600x550')
Label(sett, text = '').grid(row = 0, column =0)
Label(sett, text='')
global biriyani_entry1
global Chicken65_entry1
global coke_entry1
global vf_rice1
global samosa_entry1
global tea_entry1
global Noodles_entry1

Label(sett, text = 'Biriyani: ', font = ('calibri', 20)).grid(row=1, column =0)
biriyani_entry1 = Entry(sett, font=('calibri', 20))
biriyani_entry1.grid(row=1, column=1)
biriyani_entry1.insert(0, 200)

Label(sett, text='').grid(row=2, column=0)
Label(sett, text='').grid(row=2, column=1)

Label(sett, text='Chicken 65: ', font=('calibri', 20)).grid(row=3, column=0)
Chicken65_entry1 = Entry(sett, font=('calibri', 20))
Chicken65_entry1.grid(row=3, column=1)
Chicken65_entry1.insert(0,180)
Label(sett, text='').grid(row=4, column=0)
Label(sett, text='').grid(row=4, column=1)

Label(sett, text='Coke ', font=('calibri', 20)).grid(row=5, column=0)
coke_entry1 = Entry(sett, font=('calibri', 20))
coke_entry1.grid(row=5, column=1)
coke_entry1.insert(0,20)
Label(sett, text='').grid(row=6, column=0)
Label(sett, text='').grid(row=6, column=1)

Label(sett, text='Veg Fried Rice:  ', font=('calibri', 20)).grid(row=7, column=0)
vf_rice1 = Entry(sett, font=('calibri', 20))
vf_rice1.grid(row=7, column=1)
vf_rice1.insert(0,120)
Label(sett, text='').grid(row=8, column=0)
Label(sett, text='').grid(row=8, column=1)

Label(sett, text='Samosa ', font=('calibri', 20)).grid(row=9, column=0)
samosa_entry1 = Entry(sett, font=('calibri', 20))
samosa_entry1.grid(row=9, column=1)
samosa_entry1.insert(0,15)
Label(sett, text='').grid(row=10, column=0)
Label(sett, text='').grid(row=10, column=1)

Label(sett, text='Tea ', font=('calibri', 20)).grid(row=11, column=0)
tea_entry1 = Entry(sett, font=('calibri', 20))
tea_entry1.grid(row=11, column=1)
tea_entry1.insert(0,10)
Label(sett, text='').grid(row=12, column=0)
Label(sett, text='').grid(row=12, column=1)

Label(sett, text='Noodles ', font=('calibri', 20)).grid(row=13, column=0)
Noodles_entry1 = Entry(sett, font=('calibri', 20))
Noodles_entry1.grid(row=13, column=1)
Noodles_entry1.insert(0,150)
Label(sett, text='').grid(row=14, column=0)
Label(sett, text='').grid(row=14, column=1)
Label(sett, text='').grid(row=15, column=0)
Label(sett, text='').grid(row=15, column=1)
apply_button = Button(sett, text = 'Apply', width = 10, height =1, font=('calibri',17), relief = SOLID,command = setting_change)
apply_button.grid(row=16, column = 1 )
```

The executing function is this:

```
def setting_change():
global bir
global ch65
global coke1
global vf
global samo
global te
global ndles
bir = biriyani_entry1.get()
ch65 = Chicken65_entry1.get()
coke1 = coke_entry1.get()
vf = vf_rice1.get()
samo = samosa_entry1.get()
te = tea_entry1.get()
ndles = Noodles_entry1.get()
```

These bir,ch65 etc are the prices given as input and they will be executed when total price is calculated.

Now, when i run the program, i am always needing to go to setting and click Apply, to apply the defaults...but i want those values to be applied without clicking on apply.

Please help!

Comment: my idea is just a workaround, but given that you already wrote `setting_change()` you could try calling it once at runtime after the gui definition

Comment: Simply initialise those global variables with the required values.

Comment: adding to acw's suggestion, you could first set those variables to the default values, and then use the variables themselves during the gui definition. this will also result in a much more readable code

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to initialise those global variables with the default values:

```
# initialise default prices
bir = 200
ch65 = 180
coke1 = 20
vf = 120
samo = 15
te = 10
ndles = 150
```

Then use these variables to initialise their corresponding `Entry` widgets:

```
biriyani_entry1.insert(0, bir)
Chicken65_entry1.insert(0, ch65)
coke_entry1.insert(0, coke1)
vf_rice1.insert(0, vf)
samosa_entry1.insert(0, samo)
tea_entry1.insert(0, te)
Noodles_entry1.insert(0, ndles)
```

If you want to update the default values, then you can save the values to external file inside `setting_change()` function.  Of course you need to load the external file if it exists when program starts.